# Three rebus puzzles related to mythology

Tags: rebus

I am stuck on these rebus puzzles - does anyone know how to solve them?
I tried "star ring" for the 2nd one and I'm stuck on the 1st and the 3rd ones.

[image: three rebus puzzles]

Comment: It looks like part of the rebus is cut off on the right side. Does the container in rebus #1 read "Quaker Oats"? Also, how are you sure these rebuses are related to mythology?

Comment: it was given to me like that and its in regards to my mythology class not that the answers are related to mythology

Comment: is this homework then?

Comment: No just so we can understand it was given to solve. But im bad with the last two part of the picture i do not know if its a baby, talk and the second if its cereal or  soup

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 15):

I'm pretty sure it's

> [Epic of Gilgamesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh) starring [Humbaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbaba).

Explanation:

> A+PUCK = **Epic**
>  OVEN - N = **of**
>  GILLS - S + GA (i.e. baby talk) + MASH = **Gilgamesh**
>  STAR + RING = **starring**
>  HUM + BAA BAA = **Humbaba**

Comment: in case you need reminding of the plot, [sparknotes](http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/gilgamesh/summary.html)